# Why doesn't .replaceAll() work correctly?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have two strings.

```java
String wef = "83 Cool 4555"; // From server
String wef2 = "83 Cool 4555"; // From server

wef = wef.replaceAll("/[^A-Za-z0-9- ]/", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
wef2 = wef2.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

wef.contains(wef2); // Returns FALSE.
```

If I print out the values of `wef` and `wef2`, then compare them in a diff checker, I get this from the diff checker:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiCgX.png

There's something wrong with the spaces, even though I replace all `\\s+` with a regular space. Why doesn't .replaceAll() work correctly?

Comment: When I run this snippet, wef.contains(wef2) returns true... Have you checked the String's byte codes or copied them into a HEX editor to check if the spaces are actually spaces?

Comment: [returns true](https://tio.run/##hY9BS8NAEIXv@ysee8qim5RqQCkegrSn9mJuthXWdC2pm92ws4lo6W@PGyuIB/Eyj3nzMfPmoHolD7vXoTKKCCtV2yNru2dTV6CgQpTe1Ts0cZCUwdd2v95C@T0JHIezgTf9gjvwmyvcO2dwnec5nyHLsPCuAWnfa89@2On/MDuvjDX1ujWq0oUxCc/WT4V8VPJjIm8lthm/BOfiF7LZ0MVog4sZ@z42yt8QK98p6CZ1XUjbmDEYm4yHK2dD/JrGZirEV8YHHTpvCYtiWc7T4XQaPgE)

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. There is no `/regex/flags` syngax, but simply `regex`, possibly with `(?flags)regex`. So remove those `/`.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart unfortunately you're not getting the same values as me from my server, so my server must be returning different space values. But that begs the question why is the replaceAll("\\s", " ") not working?

Comment: @Jeffsmith, I have only one idea: whitespace != non-printable. Try to compare your strings in any byte viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the leading and trailing slashes, unless you are *actually* looking for non-alphanumeric(-hyphenic-spacic) characters surrounded by slashes:

```
wef.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9- ]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a possible reason - server's returns 'different spaces'. Take look at this code - it works exactly as you wrote:

```
    String wef = "83 Cool 4555"; // From server
    String wef2 = "83\u00A0Cool\u00A04555"; // From server

    wef = wef.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9- ]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    wef2 = wef2.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

    log.debug(wef);
    log.debug(wef2);

    assertFalse(wef.contains(wef2));
```

but output looks the same:

```
DEBUG 22:25:54.879 [main] (AAA.java:22) 83 Cool 4555
DEBUG 22:25:54.888 [main] (AAA.java:23) 83 Cool 4555
```

Why? Because in first string we have space, but in second 'non-breaking space'.